# complexity of cheriton-tarjan algorithm for MST

Tags: time-complexity, minimum-spanning-tree

A few days ago I saw a post here about the Cheriton-Tarjan algorithm which I think is an improvement of Boruvka algorithm. I think I get how it works but I don't understand why the complexity of this algorithm is O(mloglogn). Can someone plz explain it to me? thnx.

Answer (score 0):

True, the complexity of this algorithm  is O(mlog(logn)). Read this article [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zxSmHAoMiRUC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=cheriton-tarjan%20algorithm&source=bl&ots=LQWYqzK7bq&sig=mmKjYZ7pevW3vkPD1Xmg7GC5BOI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0AX4UsykO_Cp7AbWiICADg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=cheriton-tarjan%20algorithm&f=false) and i guess you will understand the algorithm and its complexity

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a reference to the 1976 paper and the complexity you quote
is only for some worse case situations. There are other complexities
quoted for other conditions.

Finding Minimum Spanning Trees

Related Databases
Web of Science
You must be logged in with an active subscription to view this.
Article Data
History
Submitted: 10  June  1975
Published online: 13 July 2006
Keywords
equivalence algorithm, graph algorithm, minimum spanning tree, priority queue
Digital Object Identifier
http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0205051
Publication Data
ISSN (print): 0097-5397
ISSN (online): 1095-7111
Publisher: Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics
David Cheriton and Robert Endre Tarjan

This paper studies methods for finding minimum spanning trees in graphs.
Results include 1.  several algorithms with $O(m\log \log n)$ worst-case
running times, where n is the number vertices and m is the number of
edges in the problem graph; 2.  an $O(m)$ worst-case algorithm for dense
graphs (those for which m is $\Omega (n^{1 + \varepsilon } )$ for some
positive constant $\varepsilon $); 3.  an $O(n)$ worst-case algorithm
for planar graphs; 4.  relationships with other problems which might
lead general lower bound for the complexity of the minimum spanning tree
problem.

Copyright © 1976 Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics

Read More: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0205051
```